# How many instances do I need for Amazon Elasticsearch Service?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

If I need a 3-node cluster do I need to have 3 instances? Or are they created in same instance?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oRAI.png

Answer (score 0):

If you need a 3-node cluster then you must have 3 instances. Node means a separate instance and 3 machine ElasticSearch cluster will have different jobs assigned to each node.

**What is an Elasticsearch cluster?**

As the name implies, an Elasticsearch cluster is a group of one or more Elasticsearch nodes instances that are connected together. The power of an Elasticsearch cluster lies in the distribution of tasks, searching and indexing, across all the nodes in the cluster.

**The nodes in the Elasticsearch cluster can be assigned different jobs or responsibilities:**

**Data Nodes** - stores data and executes data-related operations such as search and aggregation

**Master Nodes** - in charge of cluster-wide management and configuration actions such as adding and removing nodes

**Client Nodes** - forwards cluster requests to the master node and data-related requests to data nodes

**Ingest Nodes** - for pre-processing documents before indexing

By default, each node is automatically assigned a unique identifier, or name, that is used for management purposes and becomes even more important in a multi-node, or clustered, environment.

When installed, a single Elasticsearch node will form a new single-node cluster entitled **elasticsearch** but it can also be configured to join an existing cluster using the cluster name.